# FFT to compare two audio Files

Tags: pattern-matching, processing, audio-fingerprinting, minim

I am using the minim library in processing which is able to give me the FFT of an audio file. How can I use that data to compare it with another audio file and output the similarity of the two audio files ?

Comment: Did you solve your problem or not, I also have the problem.